# Dias de diferencia entre 2 fechas

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo 2 fechas diferentes, la primera de una tabla que seria t1.fecha_actual y la otra de una tabla diferente la cual seria t2.fecha_final, de estas necesito la diferencia en dias intente con algo como esto:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,t1.fecha_actual, t2.fehca_final) AS Diferencia
```

Pero me arroja un error debido a que las fecha de la t2.fecha_final esta como tipo de dato NVARCHAR y la de t1.fecha_actual como TIMESTAMP, trate con un cast dentro del mismo pero me arroja error tambien por lo tanto no se si esta bien escrito

```
CAST(t2.fecha_final AS timestamp(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.fecha_actual, t2.fecha_final)))
```

Comment: El `CAST` tendría que ser dentro del cálculo de la diferencia directamente. ¿De qué tipo es la fecha en `t1`  es `DATE` o es `DATETIME` o es `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Es TIMESTAMP @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo están los datos en `t2`? Hay que hacer una conversión correcta en esa columna, sin saber cómo están los datos es complicado. Por cierto, deberías pensar en normalizar esa columna convirtiéndola a TIMESTAMP o a un tipo adecuado para lo que ella representa.

Comment: Si seria lo mejor pero no puedo :/ en la tabla t1.fecha_actual (TIMESATAMP) "2021-04-07 14:46:48"     
 y en la t2.fecha_final (NVARCHAR)  "2021-04-14 00:00:00" (Ambas fechas corresponden al mismo usuario pero de tablas distintas ) trate con lo que me djjo pero aun me arroja error `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, (CAST(t2.fecha_final AS timestamp)), t1.fecha_actual)`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar simplemente [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), convirtiendo la fecha de `t2` a `DATETIME`, mediante `CAST`, pero esa conversión se haría dentro de la función que calcula la diferencia entre fechas, no fuera de ella.

Algo así:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(CAST(t2.fecha_final AS DATETIME),t1.fecha_actual) AS diff
```

**NÓTESE** que se pone en primer lugar la fecha más alta, de lo contrario la diferencia saldría en negativo.

Lo puedes hacer también con `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`, pero aplicando lo mismo: el `CAST` debe hacerse dentro de la función, no fuera. Aquí el orden de las fechas sería la más reciente primero y la más alta al final.

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.fecha_actual, CAST(t2.fecha_final AS DATETIME)) AS diff
```

Comment: Me tira el siguiente error >>> La función 'DATEDIFF (TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP)' no existe
No se puede identificar una función que satisfaga los tipos de argumentos dados.
Es posible que deba agregar encasillamientos explícitos @A.Cedano

Comment: @SimonPinto intenta del segundo modo, con `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, como indico al final de la respuesta. Es extraño, hice una prueba y me funciona con los dos tipos de dato. Si sigue dando problema edita tu pregunta poniendo cómo lo estás intentando en un contexto más amplio de la consulta.

Comment: @SimonPinto otro problema puede ser que alguna fila de `t2` tenga fechas no válidas, en ese caso, tendrías que verificar antes que la construcción de la fecha desde esa columna no arroja un valor nulo. Es lo que tiene declarar columnas con tipos de datos que luego admiten cualquier cosa.

Comment: Realice el ultimo ejemplo que me dio, y me tira:  Attribute 'DAY' not found  @A.Cedano

Comment: @SimonPinto ¿podrías mostrás cómo estás escribiendo la consulta actualmente?

Comment: Es exactamente igual a la ultima que me dio `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.fecha_actual, CAST(t2.fecha_final AS DATETIME)) AS diff`

Comment: @SimonPinto he probado la consulta y me funciona perfectamente. He replicado exactamente lo que has dicho, columna `fecha_actual` de tipo `TIMESTAMP` y columna `fecha_final` de tipo `NVARCHAR`. Debe haber algún en tu consulta o algo que no has dicho. Sugiero que edites la pregunta, poniendo la consulta completa que estás intentando, la estructura de las columnas y un set de datos donde estaría ocurriendo el error.

Comment: @A.Cenado bueno la fecha que es tipo `NVARCHAR` viene de una tabla con `LEFT JOIN` cruzado por el rut

Comment: @SimonPinto agrega la consulta completa a tu pregunta para revisarla. Probablemente el error que comentas estaría ocurriendo por un error en otra parte de la consulta.